# Does Spring WebFlux have analogue of Micronaut ExecuteOn annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Micronaut supports `@ExecuteOn` annotation that enables you to schedule all the handlers of a controller on IO pool:

```
@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)
@Controller
public class BookController {
    @Get("/{id}")
    Book get(Long id) {
        //This will be a thread on the IO thread pool, so it is OK to block
    }
}
```

Does Spring WebFlux has something to have the same semantics? I know how to use `Schedulers.boundedElastic()`, but sometimes we have completely blocking controllers that hit old APIs or third party libraries and want to have simpler code there.

Comment: look into the `subscribeOn`operator https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_the_subscribeon_method

Comment: This is not the same as declarative annotation. I know how to use subscribeOn, it is more verbose than just annotation on controller.

Comment: As far as I'm aware no, no such equivalent exists in Spring.